# Retrieve Data from ArrayList of hash map show null always in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to retrieve data from an arraylist of HashMap but it is always showing null. Strange the listview is showing up the data perfectly.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


 //Count from the server 
 int count = dataCount();

 for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) 
{
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

// adding data to HashMap key => value
map.put(KEY_ID, trackNumber);
map.put(KEY_TITLE, trackTitle);
map.put(KEY_ARTIST, trackArtist);
map.put(KEY_DURATION, trackDuration);
map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, trackAlbumArt);

// adding HashList to ArrayList
songsList.add(map);

}
```

I tried the below code after adding the songList it is always null... :(

```
  Log.e("Title","1"+songsList.get(0).get("KEY_TITLE"));
```

Setting the adapter here:

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: which part of code are you using the log?? post the whole block of code

Comment: While retrieving you passing key as "KEY_TITLE" while during storing you using KEY_TITLE , it could be possible KEY_TITLE value is something else in yous constant or enum file , Please make it same in both case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
 Log.e("Title","1"+songsList.get(0).get("KEY_TITLE"));
```

to

```
 Log.e("Title","1"+songsList.get(0).get(KEY_TITLE));
```

No way of telling from the code you posted, but I assume that the value of the `KEY_TITLE` constant is actually `"title"` instead of `"KEY_TITLE"`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you'r trying to fetch your data with this

```
 Log.e("Title","1"+songsList.get(0).get("KEY_TITLE"));
```

But you have may be already defined your string in declaration part. So above code gives you always null. So just change

```
 Log.e("Title","1"+songsList.get(0).get(KEY_TITLE));
```